# Rails crashes after serving a 200 OK

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
=> Booting Thin
=> Rails 4.1.6 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Notice: server is listening on all interfaces (0.0.0.0). Consider using 127.0.0.1 (--binding option)
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Thin web server (v1.7.0 codename Dunder Mifflin)
Maximum connections set to 1024
Listening on 0.0.0.0:3000, CTRL+C to stop
Started GET "/admin/performance" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-11-30 18:39:36 -0500
Processing by Admin::ReportingController#performance as HTML
  ... Rendering omitted for brevity and sanity
Completed 200 OK in 15768ms (Views: 4258.8ms | ActiveRecord: 521.3ms)
```

And then nothing. The browser still shows an open connection (renders nothing), and my Rails server crashes. Any other view sparks no output. If I force kill the server (using `kill -9 pid` because regular Ctrl-C or `kill pid` doesn't work) and restart it, everything works fine except this one particular action.

Has anyone seen anything like this? Is there a solution? It's actually working in production which uses Unicorn, so I'm thinking it might be a problem with Thin... but why would it only be an issue with one action?

EDIT: Changing to WEBrick does not solve this problem, so it's not an issue with Thin, although Ctrl-C works with WEBrick

EDIT 2: Updating rack-timeout allows the server to not hang and cancel the request

Comment: Also possibly worth noting: it works if there's an error in it (as in, the BetterErrors page shows up)

Comment: It's also reaching the end of the main layout (putting a `debugger` there gets called)

Comment: Upon further investigation, it kind of seems like the action taking a really long time causes this problem. Rendering taking a really long time doesn't matter, and it doesn't matter that the end of the controller eventually gets reached...

Comment: have you tried debugging your action ? can you paste in the code in your action ?

Comment: Yeah as I said I put a debugger at the end of the action and it gets called, so the whole thing is going through. I can't post the code because it's proprietary, but i basically realized I needed to make it run for a shorter amount of time, so I reduced some numbers and it works now. No idea why that is; I bet it's some kind of Rails 4 bug.